# Build OpenCV 4.5.5 on mac mini m1 openjdk 17

Tags: java, macos, opencv, apple-m1, openjdk-17

I'm trying to build OpenCV 4.5.5 on a mac mini m1 as follows

1. installed openjdk 17
2. created folder ~/build_opencv in user home and cd to it
3. from this folder call

> ```
> cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64 \
> -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 \
> -DWITH_OPENJPEG=OFF \
> -DWITH_IPP=OFF \
> -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
> -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv \
> -D JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/include \
> -D JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so \
> -D JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so \
> -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
> -D BUILD_opencv_java=ON \
> -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
> -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
> -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF \
> -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ../opencv-4.5.5
> ```

4. call

> ```
> make -j7
> ```

Got a lot of warnings like

```
/Users/testuser/opencv-4.5.5/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:606:29: note: expanded from macro 'png_isaligned'
   (((type)((const char*)ptr-(const char*)0) & \
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/testuser/opencv-4.5.5/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:3563:23: warning: performing pointer subtraction with a null pointer has undefined behavior [-Wnull-pointer-subtraction]
                      png_isaligned(sp, png_uint_32) &&
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/testuser/opencv-4.5.5/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:606:29: note: expanded from macro 'png_isaligned'
   (((type)((const char*)ptr-(const char*)0) & \
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/testuser/opencv-4.5.5/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:4622:34: warning: performing pointer subtraction with a null pointer has undefined behavior [-Wnull-pointer-subtraction]
         int extra = (int)((temp - (png_bytep)0) & 0x0f);
                                 ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/opencv-4.5.5/3rdparty/libpng/pngrutil.c:4626:30: warning: performing pointer subtraction with a null pointer has undefined behavior [-Wnull-pointer-subtraction]
         extra = (int)((temp - (png_bytep)0) & 0x0f);
```

and final message

```
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/backends/python/gpythonbackend.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object modules/gapi/CMakeFiles/opencv_gapi.dir/src/utils/itt.cpp.o
[ 71%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_gapi.dylib
[ 71%] Built target opencv_gapi
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Also tried openjdk 15 and 18 but led to same result.

Any ideas to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out jdk was not setup properly in $JAVA_HOME. It works now.

Comment: Can you detail what you change about JAVA_HOME? I'm having a similar issue, fails around 41%